# Wordpress pagination doens't work, just goes to the first page

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation

Suddenly my pagination stopped working. I tried turning all the plugins off, didn't work. Checked functions file, nothing weird. I have have no idea what causes the issue. Any thoughts on this? How do I make this pagination work again. I use the WP-PageNavi, but same thing is happening with standard navigation code.

My code:

```
<?php

if( is_front_page() ){
    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1; 
} else {
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
}


query_posts('posts_per_page='.get_option('posts_per_page').'&paged=' . $paged);
?>

<div id="homepage-blog" class="clr">
    <h2 class="heading">Title</h2>
    <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>

            <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>


                <?php $wpex_count++; ?>
                    <article class="recent-blog-entry clr col span_1_of_3 col-<?php echo $wpex_count; ?>">
                        <?php
                        // Display post thumbnail
                        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                            <div class="recent-blog-entry-thumbnail">
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>">
                                    <img src="<?php echo wpex_get_featured_img_url(); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" />
                                </a>
                            </div><!-- .recent-blog-entry-thumbnail -->
                        <?php } ?>
                        <header>
                            <h3 class="recent-blog-entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                            <ul class="post-meta clr">
                                <li class="meta-date"><span class="meta-date-text"><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>                                             </li>
                            </ul>

                        </header>
                        <div class="recent-blog-entry-content entry clr">
                            <?php wpex_excerpt( 18, false ); ?>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                <?php if ( $wpex_count == '3' ) { ?>
                    <?php $wpex_count=0; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php wp_pagenavi();?>
        </div>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</article>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `query_posts`. `query_posts` breaks pagination. Please see the codex if you haven't done so yet.

You must revert your changes, and see when pagination works again. It should be quite noticable that if  pagination worked before making changes and not after making changes, then your changes is your problem

Answer (score -1):

Why not revert to your last backup since you've disabled all plugins

cuz I would have said u should disable the last plugin u installed maybe it is that brought up the error

Comment: That's not a solution, last update is a while ago and i changed A LOT of things :)